# Converting pandas column with list of items to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame column like this:

```
col1
[DEBUG=true, DEBUG1=true]
[key1=true, key2=true]
```

This output DataFrame I want like this:

```
col1
{"DEBUG":"true", "DEBUG1": "true"}
{"key1":"true", "key2":"true"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are these strings or lists in "col1"?

Comment: these are list in col1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].explode().str.split('=').groupby(level=0).agg(list).apply(dict)
```

or you could use a list comprehension:

```
df['col1'] = [dict(x.split('=') for x in lst) for lst in df['col1'].tolist()]
```

Output:

```
                                  col1
0  {'DEBUG': 'true', 'DEBUG1': 'true'}
1     {'key1': 'true', 'key2': 'true'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split each value in list comprehension and convert to dictionary:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: dict(y.split('=') for y in x))
```

---

```
df['col1'] = [dict(y.split('=') for y in x) for x in df['col1']]
print (df)
                                  col1
0  {'DEBUG': 'true', 'DEBUG1': 'true'}
1     {'key1': 'true', 'key2': 'true'}
```